# What's the difference between tf.math.reduce_mean and tf.keras.metrics.Mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm confused what function to use. They look the same and do the same work. I understand that tf.keras.metrics.Mean is metric, but can't I use it somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

Functionality of tf.keras.metrics.Mean and tf.math.reduce_mean are slightly different.
Look at the example

#tf.keras.metrics.Mean: CASE1

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant([[1, 3, 5, 7],[1, 1, 0, 0]])
m = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
m.update_state(x)
m.result().numpy()
```

Output:

```
1.886
```

#tf.keras.metrics.Mean: CASE2

```
m.reset_state()
m.update_state([1, 3, 5, 7], sample_weight=[1, 1, 0, 0])
m.result().numpy()
```

Output:

```
2.0
```

#tf.math.reduce_mean

#CASE1

```
y = tf.reduce_mean(x)
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

#CASE2

```
y = tf.reduce_mean(x1,1)
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor([4 0], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
```

#CASE3

```
y = tf.reduce_mean(x1,0)
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor([1 2 2 3], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
```

In case of `tf.math.reduce_mean`, you see that when axis(numpy) is 1, it computes mean across (1, 3, 5, 7) and (1,1,0,0), so 1 defines across which axis the mean is computed. When it is 0, the mean is computed across(1,1),(3,1),(5,0) and (7,0), and so on.

Comment: How about `tf.math.reduce_mean` vs `tf.keras.backend.mean`? I get the same output with both, but is there a reason to prefer one over the other, e.g performance?